# TextRenderer.MeasureText Seems To Round Up Font Size

Tags: .net

As far as I can tell, when you use `TextRenderer.MeasureText` to find the width of a character, in my case a fixed width `CourierNew` character, I get strange results when the font size has a decimal component, eg 11.3 rather than 11.0 or 12.0.

Eg

```
Dim font As Font = New Font("Courier New", emSize:=11.3)
Dim width As Double = TextRenderer.MeasureText(New String("0"c, 1000), font).Width / 1000
```

(I'm averaging the length of a long string to account for padding.)

Results

```
emSize = 11.0 -> width = 9.008
emSize = 12.0 -> width = 10.008
emSize = 11.3 -> width = 10.008
emSize = 11.7 -> width = 10.008
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this expected behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing that the values returned by `TextRenderer.MeasureText()` are relevant for, is for knowing the text size when the text is rendered by `TextRenderer.DrawText()`. So, the question really is: do the sizes returned by `MeasureText()` match what happens when the `DrawText()` method is called. And indeed, they do:

[image: sample text, drawn four different sizes, with and without anti-aliasing, with TextRenderer and with Graphics.DrawString]

The above is the output from a simple program (code below) that renders a sample string of ten digits, in the four different font sizes you are asking about, four different ways. The first two sets are rendered using `TextRenderer.DrawText()`, while the second two sets are rendered using `Graphics.DrawString()`.

Note that when using `TextRenderer`, three of the four sizes render *exactly* the same. So, of course when you measure the text, the measured width is also going to be exactly the same.

For each of the two rendering methods used, the rendering is actually done twice, once with the default settings for the `Graphics` object, and then again with `Graphics.TextRenderingHint` set to `AntiAlias`. It is interesting to note that, at least on my computer, while having `AntiAlias` set makes the `TextRenderer` output look better, when using the `Graphics.DrawString()` method it makes it look worse (in fact, it looks a lot like the `TextRenderer` output when the setting is the default value of `SystemDefault`).

More importantly though, note that while `TextRenderer` does not scale with fractional font sizes, `Graphics.DrawString()` does. These two rendering methods are fundamentally different. If you want fractional font sizes, you need to use a rendering method that supports that. And `TextRenderer` isn't that.

**Code example:**
In a brand new Windows Form project in Visual Studio, you can add these members to the `Form1` class, to produce the output above:

```
private readonly IReadOnlyList<float> _emSizes = new[] { 11.0f, 11.3f, 11.7f, 12.0f };
private const string _text = "0123456789";

protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPaint(e);

    int y = _DrawTextExamples(e.Graphics, _text, 0, _emSizes) + 10;

    e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;
    y = _DrawTextExamples(e.Graphics, _text, y, _emSizes) + 10;
    e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.SystemDefault;
    y = _DrawTextExamplesWithDrawString(e.Graphics, _text, y, _emSizes) + 10;
    e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;
    y = _DrawTextExamplesWithDrawString(e.Graphics, _text, y, _emSizes) + 10;
}

private int _DrawTextExamples(Graphics g, string text, int y, IReadOnlyList<float> emSizes)
{
    Point pt = new Point(0, y);

    foreach (float emSize in emSizes)
    {
        using (Font font = new Font("Courier New", emSize))
        {
            Size size = TextRenderer.MeasureText(g, text, font);
            TextRenderer.DrawText(g, text, font, pt, Color.Black);
            pt.X += size.Width + 20;
            TextRenderer.DrawText(g, $"emSize: {emSize}, width: {size.Width}", font, pt, Color.Black);
            pt = new Point(0, pt.Y + size.Height);
        }
    }

    return pt.Y;
}

private int _DrawTextExamplesWithDrawString(Graphics g, string text, int y, IReadOnlyList<float> emSizes)
{
    PointF pt = new Point(0, y);

    foreach (float emSize in emSizes)
    {
        using (Font font = new Font("Courier New", emSize))
        {
            SizeF size = g.MeasureString(text, font);
            g.DrawString(text, font, Brushes.Black, pt);
            pt.X += size.Width + 20;
            g.DrawString($"emSize: {emSize}, width: {size.Width}", font, Brushes.Black, pt);
            pt = new PointF(0, pt.Y + size.Height);
        }
    }

    return (int)pt.Y + 1;
}
```